# Removing whitespace in match against search

Tags: mysql

I have database with values including whitespace. For example "LAS VEGAS". In my mysql, I am doing search using match against.

```
select * where match(city) against ("LASVEGAS")
```

Its not returning any rows because its searching in database without whitespace. Can anyone please help me do search including whitespace.

Comment: What stops you from using "LAS VEGAS"?

Comment: Its not sure that user always enter with whitespace. They might enter "LASVEGAS" and expecting records. But its not coming. other examples are New york,San jose, San fransisco.

Comment: Your forgetting a `from` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` to remove whitespace within the query

```
select * from cityTable where replace(city," ","")="LASVEGAS"
```

You can read more about the `replace` function [here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php)!

**Edit: match is required**

Since match is required and since you can't use replace inside match I'm suggesting a middle way here. (My real suggestion is to not use `fulltext`-index with `match` and `against` on a column as simple as the city column but sometimes you have requirements that forces you to make strange solutions)

By creating a "search friendly" city column (with `fulltext` index support) next to the ordinary city column, where you remove all white-spaces and dashes, you can try to get around this problem.

```
|     City      |  CitySearch  |
|===============|==============|
|   Las Vegas   |   LasVegas   |
| San Francisco | SanFrancisco |
| Saint-Quentin | SaintQuentin |
```

When you later on make a search you can search with `match` and `against` on the `CitySearch` column instead. When user types a city name that you want to search on you first have to clear it in the same way you've cleared the `City` column. Now it doesn't matter if the user writes "Las Vegas", "Las-Vegas" or "LasVegas" because after clearing the user data you'll end up with "LasVegas" to search for against the `CitySearch` column.

The sql query would be:

```
select * from cityTable where match(CitySearch) against ("LasVegas")
```

I hope this will be within the requirements you have

Comment: Thanks. Can you tel me how to use replace in match,against.           select * from cityTable  where match(`city`) against (replace(city," ","")="LASVEGAS") . This is giving error

Comment: The sql query I wrote is a real one. Just replace `cityTable` with the name of your table and "LasVegas" with whatever the user is writing (don't forget to clear the user's value so you won't end up with SQL injection)

Comment: I added a link in my answer where you can read more about the `replace` function in MySQL.

Comment: Remove `match(city)` and only write what I wrote. You have to replace `cityTable` with the name of your table also.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to use match . Please tell me how to use replace inside match

Comment: I've done some search and found out that you can't use replace inside a match. You never wrote that match was a requirement and that's why I suggested replace. If match is a requirement then I would create a specific "search friendly" city column next to the ordinary column where all whitespaces, dashes etc are removed. I'll update my answer with some samples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are pulling your search term from outside application I think you could pretty easily convert to a Regular Expression check.

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.city REGEX 'L\s?A\s?S\s?V\s?E\s?G\s?A\s?S';
```

This will pull from your table any version of LASVEGAS including whitespace inserted.  Here every \s? represents an optional whitespace.  I'm no REGEX expert, but here is the mysql docs link.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html